# Sum two columns in R such that NA+NA=NA, but NA+(a number)=0+(a number)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which is composed of NA's and numbers. It looks like this:

```
   a  b
1  1  3
2 NA NA
3  3  2
4 NA  1
5  4 NA
```

I'd like to be able to sum two columns in this dataframe such that NA+NA=NA, but NA should be treated as 0 when it is being summed with a number. For example, the sum of 'a' and 'b' from the dataframe above should look like this:

```
  sum
1   4
2  NA
3   5
4   1
5   4
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: Try with `rowSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)* NA^(rowSums(is.na(df1))==2)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE` to remove the NAs while doing the sum over the row.  Make sure to change the rows that are all `NAs`  to NA

```
v1 <- unname(rowSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)* NA^(rowSums(is.na(df1))==2))
data.frame(Sum = v1)
# Sum
#1   4
#2  NA
#3   5
#4   1
#5   4
```

---

Or with `apply` and `sum_`

```
library(hablar)
as.vector(apply(df1, 1,  sum_))
#[1]  4 NA  5  1  4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L), b = c(3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"))
```

Comment: I've never see that `NA^` notation before.  What would I search for, in order to read more about it?

Comment: @DavidT it is a hacky way to return 1 and NA. i.e. `NA^c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)` returns `NA 1 NA`  In the code, I am returning TRUE where both the columns are NA with rowSums `== 2`

Comment: @DavidT  I  would say that I am making use of this property `NA^1
[#1] NA`
and `NA^0
[1] 1`  However a more readable option  is `ifelse`  or `case_when`

Comment: I learn something new every day.  Especially when I read your code.